# Choosing a result from a search query using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I understand so far how to search from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184407/4322850

But my question isn't so mush as to how to perform a query using jsoup. It's more of how do I select something loaded. As in if I go to Google and search, how can I select one of the returned links?

**Edit:
This was the question asked**

I have a piece of html code which represents a part of a website that is supposed to be the search widget for a directory of a faculty in a university

```
<div id="right_column" class="content_main"> <div class="searchbox"> <form method="POST" action="/faculty/directory_search/" id="searchform"> <h4>Search the Directory</h4> <input type="text" name="searchterms" value="" /> <select name="category" class="dropdown"> <option value="all" selected="selected">All Categories</option> <option value="Faculty">Faculty</option> <option value="Staff">Staff</option> <option value="Visitors">Visitors</option> <option value="Full time">Full time</option> <option value="Visiting">Visiting</option> <option value="Special Appointment">Special Appointment</option> <option value="Biological Sciences">Biological Sciences</option> </select> <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="asc" /> <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search directory" /> <a class="button" href="/faculty/index/desc" id="sortbutton">Sort Alphabetically</a> </form> <script type="text/javascript"> $('#searchform').ready(function(){ $('#sortbutton').click(function(){ $('input[name="sort"]').val('desc'); $('#searchform').submit(); return false; }); }); </script> </div>
```

I am trying to input the name "john" and submit the search using jsoup using the following java code (intended for android but it's overall the same java code as for a regular java app)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/directory/").data("searchterms", "john").post();
```

However, I keep getting the same page as just "http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/directory/" with no search submitted. I noticed that in the html code there is the submit input type. I'm wondering if I had to submit the search. If so, how can it be done?

**This was the answer of that question**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/faculty/directory_search/").data("searchterms", "john").data("sort", "asc").data("category", "all").post();
```

This answer is not working for me.

Comment: Post your own self-contained question please, you can't have half of the question in a link to another question.

Comment: Is that answer work for you ?

Comment: That one answers how do search, but that returns a page that was searched. What I need is to actually select something after this search page. Ex. I go to Google and search for "Newegg", now the page returned is the search results. I want to actually select the first link in the search results.

Comment: The answer depends on the site you are accessing - There is no such a thing "search query's result". Each site will return a different response with a different structure, so you'll have to parse it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit the form using Jsoup, instead when you submit the form manually, monitor the network tab of the inspect element on your browser. You will see that on which url the request is sending, which type etc.

I have monitor the network tab and found that when i query for john with category all they are sending http get request to this url : http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/?feed=directory&q=john&category=0&subcategory=&employeeType=0&page=1. It response a json object. You can parse that easily

Here is the Example Code to get the json response of the search result :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JSONObject data = getJSONObjectFromUrl("http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/?feed=directory&q=john&category=0&subcategory=&employeeType=0&page=1");
    System.out.println(data);
}

private static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    StringBuffer response;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }

    return new JSONObject(response.toString());
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to do this with a query to not return a category all, will it still be returning a json object?

Comment: @A.Angee Sorry i don't understand

Comment: You said "...when I query for John with category all. It response a json object. You can parse that easily." My question is if I don't do a category all, will I still be returning a json object? Also, will this return 1 entry like the example I gave above?

Comment: It's always return json even if you specify category or not

Comment: Thank you so much!